# how to add component programmatically on fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can any one please tell me how to add `TextField` and `ImageView` on fragment programmatically .With Sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create TextView and ImageView in onCreateView

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, null);

        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());

                root.addView(textView);
                root.addView(imageView);

        return root;
    }
```

fragment_layout.xml can contain any layout (FrameLayout, RelativeLayout and so on)

Comment: Thanks..What if I want to create it on button click..

Comment: Then, you should make "root" as class field, and in OnClickListener call creating textView and ImageView and adding to root

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onViewCreated () {      
AbsoluteLayout alo = (AbsoluteLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.container);
    TextView Tv = new Textview(this.getActivity());
    Tv.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(10,10,40,40));
    Tv.setText("Added");
    alo.addView((View)Tv);
}
```

You can derive from Fragment and create a method, which also does this.